# Errors when creating a Value and Timestamp dataframe with Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm not too familiar with Spark but I'm forced to use it to consume some data.  I've tried basically every syntax I could find to make a dataframe with a value and a timestamp that I can put into a database to track when I get updates from the datasource.  The errors are endless and I'm out of ideas and short on reasons for why I can't make something this simple.  Below is the sample of code I'm trying to get working

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
df = sc.parallelize([[1,pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp()]]).toDF(("Value","CreatedAt"))
```

and this error doesn't really help

```
 py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <command-1699228214903488> in <module>
      29 
      30 sc = spark.sparkContext
 ---> 31 df = sc.parallelize([[1,pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp()]]).toDF(("Value","CreatedAt"))

 /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in parallelize(self, c, numSlices)
     557                 return self._jvm.PythonParallelizeServer(self._jsc.sc(), numSlices)
     558 
 --> 559             jrdd = self._serialize_to_jvm(c, serializer, reader_func, createRDDServer)
     560 
     561         return RDD(jrdd, self, serializer)

 /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _serialize_to_jvm(self, data, serializer, reader_func, createRDDServer)
     590             try:
     591                 try:
 --> 592                     serializer.dump_stream(data, tempFile)
     593                 finally:
     594                     tempFile.close()
```

I've also tried this

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) # sc is the spark context

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
     [( current_timestamp(), '12a345')],
     ['CreatedAt','Value'] # the row header/column labels should be entered here
)
```

With the error

```
AssertionError: dataType <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7f43d97c6ba8> should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2294571935273349> in <module>
     33 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
     34     [( current_timestamp(), '12a345')],
---> 35     ['CreatedAt','Value'] # the row header/column labels should be entered here
     36 )
     37 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    305         Py4JJavaError: ...
    306         """
--> 307         return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    308 
    309     @since(1.3)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    815                 rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    816             else:
--> 817                 rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    818             jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I code something to work eventually.  I couldn't get it to work with TimestampType() though, spark would flip out when inserting the data.  I think that may be a runtime error and not a coding issue though.

```
 import adal
 import datetime;
 from pyspark.sql.types import *

 # Set Access Token
 access_token = token["accessToken"]
 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) # sc is the spark context

 schema = StructType([
     StructField("CreatedAt", StringType(), True),
     StructField("value", StringType(), True)
 ])

 da =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
     [(da,'12a345')],schema
 )                            

 df.write \
   .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
   .option("url", url)\
   .option("dbtable", "dbo.RunStart")\
   .option("accessToken", access_token)\
   .option("databaseName", database_name) \
   .option("encrypt", "true")\
   .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net")\
   .option("applicationintent", "ReadWrite") \
   .mode("append") \
   .save()
```